# JS undefined is not an object in Safari

Tags: javascript, safari

```
HeaderView.prototype.fixWonkyLogo = function() {
    var branding, logo, logoHeight;
    if (theme.ltIE9) {
        return;
    }
    logoHeight = parseInt("{{ settings.logo-height }}");
    if (this.body.hasClass("alternate-index-layout")) {
        branding = this.body;
        logo = $(".logo-regular");
    } else {
        branding = this.$(".branding");
        logo = this.$(".logo-retina").is(":visible") ? this.$(".logo-retina") : this.$(".logo-regular");
    }
}
```

***EDIT***
*Added in code snippet above*

```
return branding.imagesLoaded((function(_this) {
    return function() {
        var initialAspectRatio, newAspectRatio;
        initialAspectRatio = logo[0].naturalWidth / logo[0].naturalHeight;
        initialAspectRatio = Math.round(initialAspectRatio * 10) / 10;
        newAspectRatio = logo[0].width / logoHeight;
        newAspectRatio = Math.round(newAspectRatio * 10) / 10;
        if ((newAspectRatio !== initialAspectRatio) && (logo[0].height <= logoHeight)) {
            return logo.css({
                height: "auto"
            });
        } else {
            return logo.css({
                height: logoHeight
            });
        }
    };
})(this));
```

I'm getting this error when I view my site in Safari `undefined is not an object (evaluating 'logo[0].naturalWidth')` but when I view it in Chrome everything works fine and I get no errors.

What does Safari do/depend on differently than Chrome that could throw this error? Thanks!

Comment: where is `logo` defined/initialized?

Comment: @Andrey sorry should of thought! I've updated the question. The thing that's really confusing me is it's working in Chrome so i'm confused why it would complain about it on Safari but not Chrome if it was an issue with me initialising something

Comment: So it looks like `logo` is undefined on `imagesLoaded` callback, which means `HeaderView.prototype.fixWonkyLogo` wasn't called at all (before callback) or `theme.ltIE9` is true.

Comment: Thanks @Andrey i'm not getting into the if statement so I know it's an issue with the logo. I console logged it and get nothing back in Safari but in Chrome I get back what I expect to get back which is really odd. Thanks for pointing me in the right direction. Any reason you may know of what could be causing this in Safari?

Comment: I don't know, it is probably some problems with global window, where `logo` should be, but i can't tell you exactly, because I can't see the flow of your code, you listed just 2 separate functions. If you can create fiddle where problem is reproduced - it will be much easier

Comment: Btw, `logo` is local variable of `fixWonkyLogo` function. So it shouldn't be visible in imagesLoaded callback, so it is surprising, that it works in chrome